# Calculating resistor divider ratio with load resistor value input and output voltage given

Tags: resistors

In the given circuit, the variable resistor R = 1MΩ is connected as shown to a load RL = 1MΩ. The
variable resistor is adjusted until the voltage V
 across the load is 8 V when the input voltage Vin =
27 V. What is the position of the wiper arm in percentage?

***This is the question. I have solve it and my answer is 42%, but the solution said 36%.***

[image: Schematic of load RL connected to the tap of a potentiometer R over a voltage source VIN]

My Calculation 
[image: My equations]

Comment: Show your calculation

Comment: You can see it now

Comment: How about rotating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached it looking at the circuit as the following with \$R=1\:\textrm{M}\Omega\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUgVpE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The central node voltage of such a resistor arrangement is easy to memorize:

$$V_o=\frac{V_1\cdot R_2\cdot R_3 + V_2\cdot R_1\cdot R_3+V_3\cdot R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1\cdot R_2+R_1\cdot R_3+R_2\cdot R_3}$$

In this case, \$V_1=V_2=0\:\textrm{V}\$, so:

$$\begin{align*}
V_O&=\frac{V_3\cdot D\cdot R\cdot R}{D\cdot R\cdot R+D\cdot R\cdot \left(1-D\right)\cdot R+R\cdot \left(1-D\right)\cdot R}\\\\ &=\frac{V_3\cdot D\cdot R^2}{\left(D+D\cdot \left(1-D\right)+\left(1-D\right)\right)\cdot R^2}\\\\ &=V_3\cdot\frac{D}{D+D-D^2+1-D}=V_3\cdot\frac{D}{-D^2+D+1}
\end{align*}$$

Which is the same thing Andy came up with. Shuffling things around, you get a quadratic and a solution:

$$\begin{align*}
-V_O\cdot D^2 + (V_O-V_3)\cdot D + V_O&=0, ~~~~~\textrm{where }a=-V_O, b= V_O-V_3, c=V_O\\ \\
\therefore D &= \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a}\\\\ &=\frac{-\left(V_O-V_3\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(V_O-V_3\right)^2-4\cdot\left(-V_O\right)\cdot V_O}}{2\cdot\left(-V_O\right)} \\ \\ &=\frac{V_3-V_O\pm\sqrt{V_3^2-2\cdot V_O\cdot V_3+5\cdot V_O^2}}{-2\cdot V_O}\\ \\ &\approx -2.73996779, 0.364967794
\end{align*}$$

Clearly, the negative value isn't permitted here. So the answer is 36.5% (or rounding one digit further, 36%.)

---

Now you've got different ways of thinking about it. Pick one that sings in your mind better and go with it.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear you have made an incorrect assumption that the current does not change when the variable resistor is changed.

So, we can divide the variable resistor into R1 and R2 such that R1 + R2 = R, then assign current I to the wire adjecent to VIN and RTOTAL = R1 + (R2 || RL).

```
v = r * i
27 = RTOTAL * I
8 = R2 || RL * I
27/RTOTAL = 8/(R2 || RL)
27/8 = RTOTAL/(R2 || RL)
27/8 = (R1 + (R2 || RL))/(R2 || RL)
27/8 - 1 = R1/(R2 || RL)
2.375 = R1/((1000000 - R1) || 1000000)
2.375 = R1/(1/(1/(1000000 - R1) + 1/1000000)))
R1 = 635032
R2 = 1000000 - 635032
R2 = 364968
```

Or ~36% of the original 100% setting

Comment: Yeah, I though about it, but I couldn't find any other way!

Comment: Why did you divide the voltage 27 function over 8 function, not the opposite way?  Line.5

Comment: To get from line 4 to line 5: (1) Multiply both sides by RTOTAL & (2) Divide both sides by 8. Why?  I wanted all the numbers on one side and all the resistors on the other.

Answer (score 0):

If both variable resistor and load resistor are the same end to end value (call it R) then the voltage at the wiper can be determined by the following for a potential divider: -

Lower resistance = \$\dfrac{DR^2}{DR+R}\$

Where D is a number between 0 and 1 that represents the wiper position.

Upper resistance = \$(1-D)R\$

Next, combine these to form the potential divider equation: -

\$\dfrac{V_O}{V_I} = \dfrac{\dfrac{DR^2}{DR+R}}{\dfrac{DR^2}{DR+R}+(1-D)R}\$

Multiply through by DR+R to get: -

\$\dfrac{DR^2}{DR^2+R^2(1-D^2)}\$

It should be obvious that R totally can be removed from the equation leaving: -

\$\dfrac{D}{D+1-D^2}\$ and this equals 8/27

Can you solve it from here using the solution to a quadratic?

Note, that if I put 0.36 in for D I get the ratio of out to in of 0.2926 which isn't quite 8/27 - it would imply an output voltage of 7.9002 volts so maybe the 36% is rounded?